# Online Playing for Age of Empires - Conquerors

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings

I am looking for a place to play AOE 2 TC online - something like Battle.NET.

I used to play in Game Zone, but I think this game is no longer supported.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[http://voobly.com](http://www.voobly.com/) supports AoE II. In fact, the Conquerors is the most played game there.

It is an attempt to replace Zone.com, the original service for playing AoE II and The Conquerors online.

Answer (score 2):

You can also check http://www.gameranger.com, they have a nice client too .